# INSERT NEW STRING BETWEEN TWO STRING STATEMENTS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, terminal

I have a number of multiline text files in the form of

```
222 333 444 _benny
300 400 500 _andrew
311 411 511 _reusee
322 433 544 _benny
500 500 600 _andrew
```

I need to take out strings from _benny to _andrew and insert one more string with _yahoi between them so that the output becomes

```
222 333 444 _benny
250 321 422 _yahoii
300 400 500 _andrew
```

I tried with`awk '/_benny/,/_andrew/' filename`

but it only displayed the text

Comment: what are the first fields? only one time or for each _benny/_andrew?

Comment: For each of the entries

Comment: `300 400 500 _andrew` is the second line in the file. What happened to the rest. why isnt it from the first line till the line `500 500 600 _andrew`

Comment: rest will also be updated

Comment: You need to clarify using what logic your output should be generated?

Comment: "I tried with ... but it only displayed the text" - which is exactly what you asked it to do. Is there a reason you expected something different?

Comment: What do you want to do if a "_benny" appears after the first _benny but before the first _andrew? Come up with some more interesting sample input that includes rainy day cases and show the expected output. Scripts that handle sunny day stuff like you've shown so far are always trivial to write and usually wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk script

```
awk '/_benny/,/_andrew/ { if ( $0 ~ /_benny/ ) { print $0; print "250 321 422 _yahoii"; next } { print } }' filename
```

will yield the (assumingly) desired result

```
222 333 444 _benny
250 321 422 _yahoii
300 400 500 _andrew
322 433 544 _benny
250 321 422 _yahoii
500 500 600 _andrew
```

Avoiding `/start/,/end/` as per @ed-morton's comment you could alternatively try this:

```
awk '{ if ( $0 ~ /_benny/ || $0 ~ /_andrew/ ) { if ( $0 ~ /_benny/ ) { print $0; print "250 321 422 _yahoii"; next } { print } } }' filename
```

Comment: never use `/start/,/end/` as it makes trivial things slightly briefer but even slightly non-trivial things require a complete re-write and/or duplication of conditions (as you have). Always use `/start/{f=1} f; /end/{f=0}` or similar instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'm no awk expert so if you'd care to illustrate your advice with a corrected version of my script that'd be awsome.

Comment: `awk '/_benny/{f=1; $0 = $0 ORS "250 321 422 _yahoii"} f; /_andrew/{f=0}' file`